# Как определить в какой позиции в текстовом поле стоит курсор?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть кнопки "виртуальной клавиатуры", с помощью которых в текстовые поля  вводятся символы другого языка, которых у "среднестатистического" пользователя на клавиатуре нет.

Сейчас это работает следующим образом: когда текстовое поле теряет фокус, его id запоминается в переменной, т.е в этой переменной находится id последнего инпута, в котором был курсор. Если теперь пользователь кликает по кнопкам виртуальной клавиатуры, то в конец этого текстового поля добавляется соответствующий символ. Это просто...

Но, допустим, символ нужно добавить не в конец строки в поле, а в середину, т.е. курсор в этом поле стоял посередине слова. Можно по focusout запоминать, вместе с id поля, в какой позиции стоял курсор в поле, но как определить в какой позиции в тексте в поле находится курсор? Что-то не могу сообразить, подскажите, плиз :)

Comment: bump. Сам ищу ответ.

Comment: похоже, что стандартных методов определить это нет. Из идей, что приходят в голову: по focusout вызывать программно presskey и добавлять в текст какой-либо спецсимвол (наверное, желательно какой-ть невидимый ... какие тут варианты есть?), после определять позицию этого "спецсимвола" и запоминать ее, а спецсимвол удалять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите пример [здесь](http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/), вроде небольшой объем кода.